# excel vba blank subtotal cells don't accept a formula

Tags: excel, text, excel-formula, vba

After using Subtotals, I have some cells in the subtotals rows where I want to enter a non-subtotal formula, such as a vlookup.
When I try to use any formula on a blank cell in Subtotal row, the formula I enter, is not calculated, as if Excel defined that any not subtotal row has to be text. Instead of giving me a result, it shows the text verbatim: =VLOOKUP(K9,PartnList!$A$3:$C$119,2,FALSE)

Is there a way to change the "type" of a cell in a subtotal row so it accepts a formula? I want to do this via VBA repetitively, but first I want to know how to achieve it straightforward in Excel.

Comment: In the `Ribbon` go to `Formulas > Show Formulas` (in the `Formula Auditing `section) and make sure `Show Formulas` is not pressed (highlighted). Otherwise show a screenshot of your issue. It will help us help you better.

Answer (score 0):

My mistake, but this could very well be something that happened to other people.
The blank cells in question (created by the Subtotals function) became of type Text. Strictly Text, which means that any formula written there would not be seen as a formula but as text.

By reformatting the cells as General, you can add then a vlookup (or any formula for that matter) to the newly created subtotal cells that are blank).
Once they are reformatted, the problem disappears.